# What is "WWWW" and how we can get it for our web sites

Tags: web, www-mechanize

i know what is "www" but, when i was tring to open blogspot and by mistaken i have written 4 times "W" instead of 3 like :

http://wwww.blogspot.com/

and the page opend in front me shocked me.

please tell me what is meaning of "wwww"

and what is technique and logic behind it.

and how we can Launch our website with "wwww".

Thanks

Comment: This is just a question of confusion.. no need to close this..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this case the clever person with the blog wwww has that subdomain at blogspot with the name `wwww`

Comment: really!.. but why blogspot will alow such thing on its domain.

Comment: i guess they didn't expect it as they must have only reserved `www`, as `wwww` to `wwwwwwwwwwww` are in use as blog locations

Comment: Technically, `www.` is also a subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

'wwww' is a sub-domain - in this case it appears to be the name of the blog on Blogspot.

However, most hosting packages allow you to set up custom sub-domains (like `blog.example.com`) which can redirect anywhere you want. You could set up a `wwww.example.com` sub-domain, but there wouldn't be much point unless people regularly misspelled the name of the site (and would potentially be quite confusing too).

Comment: What: wow.. got it. but dont you think there should be check for noise word while creating blog name by blog spot?

Comment: Well, if it doesn't conflict with any reserved ones, why not let them register it?

Answer (score 0):

Blogspot blogs all have an URL in the form of `userorblogname.blogspot.com`. `wwww.blogspot.com` simply takes you to the blog called `wwww`.